# Add Image instead of largeTitle in NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift

I have a large title in a ViewController. Instead of some title I want to set an image due to I can't set attributed string.

So I want to replace this construction:

```
navigationItem.title = "Some large title"
```

To something like this:

```
let UIImageView = UImageView(image: UIImage(named: "kinopoisk_main_logo"))
navigationItem.title = "Some large title"
```

But as you may know it's unavailable. Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 13.0-iOS 15.0+, Xcode 13.2 Beta**

So, I figured it out. I made a realization with a custom NavigationBar:

```
public class NavigationBar: UINavigationBar {
    private lazy var someImageView: UIImageView = {
        let largeTitleImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "some_image"))
        largeTitleImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return largeTitleImage
    }()
    ...
    override public func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setupAttributesForLargeTitle()
    }
    ...
    private func setupAttributesForLargeTitle() {
        if let largeTitle = subviews.filter({ NSStringFromClass(type(of: $0)).contains("LargeTitleView") }).first {
            for subview in largeTitle.subviews {
                if *Some boolean value indicating largeTitle* {
                    subview.addSubview(someImageView)
                } else {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Briefly: I am getting to the deepest view in hierarchy of NavBar views and adding new subview with image to this hierarchy

**Important note:**

Don't use with this hack:

```
navigationItem.title
```